# Spring Batch MultiResourceItemReader re-reading first resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am writing a Spring Batch application using Spring Boot 1.5, following are my classes : -

`CustomMultiResourceItemReader.java`

```
@StepScoped
@Component
public class CustomMultiResourceItemReader
        extends MultiResourceItemReader<MyDTO> {

    public MultiResourceXmlItemReader(
            @NonNull final MyResourceAwareItemReader itemReader,
            @NonNull final ApplicationContext ctx)
            throws IOException {
        setResources(
                ctx.getResources(
                        String.format(
                                "file:%s/*.xml", "~/data"))); // gives me a Resource[] array fine
        setDelegate(itemReader);
    }

    @PreDestroy
    void destroy() {
        close();
    }
}
```

`MyResourceAwareItemReader.java`

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@StepScope
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyResourceAwareItemReader
        implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<MyDTO> {
    private static final String RESOURCE_NAME_KEY = "RESOURCE_NAME_KEY";
    @NonNull private final Unmarshaller unmarshaller; // JaxB Unmarshaller
    private Resource resource;

    @Override
    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource; // **gets called only once**
    }

    @Override
    public MyDTO read() throws Exception {
        final MyDTO dto = (MyDTO) unmarshaller.unmarshal(resource.getFile()); // Standard JaxB unmarshalling.
        return dto;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        if (executionContext.containsKey(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY)) {

        } else if (resource != null) {
            executionContext.put(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, resource.getFilename());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        if (resource != null) executionContext.put(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, resource.getFilename());
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {}
}
```

The problem is the `setResource` method in the `delegate` reader (**MyResourceAwareItemReader.java**) gets called only once at the beginning; while the read method gets called multiple times, as a result I read the same item multiple times, instead of reading the next item as expected.

I have also browsed the source code of [MultiResouceItemReader in Spring Batch](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/MultiResourceItemReader.java), it seems like, the read method of the delegate class is supposed to return null after each item is read, I can clearly see my code doesnt seem to do that.

I am bit lost how to make this work. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Looking further into it, `ItemReader` documentation, clearly details that reader **must** return `null` at the end of the input data set. So basically I implemented my `ItemReader` with a `boolean` flag as follows: -

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@StepScope
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MyResourceAwareItemReader
        implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<MyDTO> {
    private static final String RESOURCE_NAME_KEY = "RESOURCE_NAME_KEY";
    @NonNull private final Unmarshaller unmarshaller; // JaxB Unmarshaller
    private Resource resource;
    private boolean isResourceRead;

    @Override
    public void setResource(Resource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
        isResourceRead = false;
    }

    @Override
    public MyDTO read() throws Exception {
        if(isResourceRead == true) return null;

        final MyDTO dto = (MyDTO) unmarshaller.unmarshal(resource.getFile());
        isResourceRead = true;
        return dto;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        if (executionContext.containsKey(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY)) {

        } else if (resource != null) {
            executionContext.put(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, resource.getFilename());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        if (resource != null) executionContext.put(RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, resource.getFilename());
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {}
}
```

Comment: Failure to return `null` in any reader will always result in a loop; yes

Answer (score 0):

`MultiResourceItemReader` does not returns null each time. If there are no more resources to  read the it returns NULL otherwise it returns the next resources to the delegate  that means – Your actual reader

I can see problem in your `read()` method . y**ou are not moving to next file**. As you are implementing you own `MultiResourceItemReader` It’s   your responsibility to  move to next resources item.

This is how it is implanted in    `MultiResourceItemReader` . You will need your own similar implementation.

```
private T readNextItem() throws Exception {

        T item = delegate.read();

        while (item == null) {

            currentResource++;

            if (currentResource >= resources.length) {
                return null;
            }

            delegate.close();
            delegate.setResource(resources[currentResource]);
            delegate.open(new ExecutionContext());

            item = delegate.read();
        }

        return item;
    }
```

You need to maintain index of resources array . Please check implementation   of `MultiResourceItemReader`. You need to do exactly similar way

Comment: I **didn't** implement my own `MultiResourceItemReader`; I just set 2 properties in a constructor.

I did implement my own `ResourceAwareItemStreamReader` and in its read method I read and return the resource.

But if u see the code of the `MultiResourceItemReader.java` from Spring batch it increments the `Resource[]` index when the read method of the delegate returns null.